# How do I debug an error that a plugin is causing?

Tags: plugin-development, database, errors, debug

I'm having an issue debugging why the plugin I'm creating keeps displaying the error `You need to upgrade your database as soon as possible...`.

The work I've done so far has been on a remote dev site, and everything seems to work fine there - with no errors at all. I decided to test what would happen when I throw the plugin into a different environment to see if it would still work fine. Bare in mind that both versions of WordPress are `3.9.1`. The plugin has remained the same, but the servers are different. The only other different thing between the two is one is a multi-site (the original dev site), and the other is just a standard WP install.

The first issue I resolved, which was a problem within the way I was creating new tables. For some reason `replace` as a field name was fine on the dev site, but on the vps it wasn't. Possibly due to different versions of MySQL.

I was wondering if there is a way to debug what is happening? Why would the database need upgraded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to to find out what your current version of MYSQL...

WordPress requires MySQL 5.0 or greater

Since its a VPS, I'm assuming its a linux installation. Just type

```
mysql -V
```

on the command line and it will return your MYSQL version.

If the version is compatible with wordpress, this message may be a "plugin/theme related" message. Look at your plugins and themes and see if any of them have a specific MySQL requirement.

Comment: You would be correct in thinking it is a linux box, here's the output of that command: `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.38, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1`

Comment: It's compatible with wordpress. This means you're error must be coming from a plugin/script... If you google, "You need to upgrade your database as soon as possible..." you get a snippet example on how to create an admin message. Can you check your functions.php if it has this snippet?

Comment: If you mean the one found here: http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/super-useful-wordpress-action-hooks-and-filters then yes I have part of that code `function showMessage()`, but I don't have the one that says the message `You need to upgrade your database as soon as possible...` which is `function showAdminMessages()`.

Comment: You've narrowed it down to plugin related then. I don't think its an Official WordPress Error code. If I were in your shoes, at this point I'd do a string search for "You need to upgrade your database as soon as possible..." on all files in the plugins folder to see which files have it. :)

Comment: I will do, thank you for your help. I'll report back once I've done it.

Comment: Bah, you were right, it was something I put in the plugin after all - and here was me going nuts over it! It's still strange that it shows up in the vps but not on the dev site.

Comment: I know the feeling. Something like this happens to me when I code for hours on end. Glad you found it!